# How to union two different data frames in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames i wish to join together. The first, contains a load of stores, represented by their id, and holds information about them such as number of sales (weekly_sales) and the date representing that week.

[image]

The second, contains additional data for some of the stores, for some of their weeks, such as fuel price for that week.

[image]

I need to create one data frame that combines the two. So for each store id and date combo in the first data set that is also in the second data set, i would have the following, which is the first data set and the temperature and fuel price from the second data set added to the correct row from the first data set:

[image]

As the third entry has a store id and date combo not shared between the first and second data sets, i would just have the new columns be NA.

How would I do this in spark? The only unions i know how to do are just basic joins based on equal data sets.

Data sets in text:

```
Store   Dept    Date    Weekly_Sales    IsHoliday
1       1   05/02/2010   24924.5        FALSE
1       1   12/02/2010   46039.49       TRUE
1       1   19/02/2010   41595.55       FALSE
1       1   26/02/2010   19403.54       FALSE
1       1   05/03/2010   21827.9        FALSE


Store   Date    Temperature Fuel_Price
1     05/02/2010    42.31     2.572
1     12/02/2010    38.51     2.548
1     19/02/2010    39.93     2.514
1     26/02/2010    46.63     2.561
1     05/03/2010    46.5      2.625
1     12/03/2010    57.79     2.667

Store   Dept    Date    Weekly_Sales    IsHoliday   Temparat Fuel_Price
1       1     05/02/2010    24924.5      FALSE      42.31      2.572
1       1     12/02/2010    46039.49     TRUE       38.51      2.548
1       1     06/02/2010    41595.55     FALSE      NA         NA
1       1     26/02/2010    19403.54     FALSE      
1       1     05/03/2010    21827.9      FALSE      
1       1     12/03/2010    21043.39     FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you could just perform a `join` with the `Store` and `date` fields as

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("Store", "date"), "left")
```

This should give you required output.